# RGB from three different rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, rgb

I did an RGB image from three different rasters (red, green & blue for the same date and place) using ArcGIS tool "Composite bands".

The result does not seems correct :

[image]

and this is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea why this is not working? Does it comes from my manipulation or my data (Landsat 8 PAR images)